# test algorithm to decide if point is inside area

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

here's a geometric problem that I've been unsuccessful to solve:

- we have four points ***A, B, C, D*** defining an area
- and two points ***E, F***
- ***E*** is within the boundaries of the polygon ***ABCD***
- ***F*** is outside the borders

We know the ***(x, y)*** coordinates of each point.

(see the figure below)

[image: illustration]

Determine for any point
***G (x, y)*** if ***G*** is inside or outside ***ABCD***

Any ideas out there?

Thanks
Adrien

Comment: This sounds like math.

Comment: Also, as a hint, the fact that this is not a "concave" shape will be a key to solving this puzzle.

Comment: Step one: find a point that's guaranteed to be outside of the poligon

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: Well, the generalized question is [one of the most popular on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test). I wouldn't say it's off-topic, it's just computational geometry.

Comment: @JerryCoffin well no, inside of a rectangle is very easy...

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com: Axis aligned rectangles, yes. The other question asks about rotated rectangles, and Jerry's answer also provides information for general polygons.

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com: The fact that the points might not form a rectangle doesn't change the validity of (at least some of) the answers given to those.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Okay I think I got a part, I can first trace a rectange with min/max x,y coordinates, then check if G_x is inferior to the min_x value or superior to the max_x, same with G_y and min_y, max_y, then there's only triangles left, so it becomes a problem of "is it inside triangles... Is that it?

Comment: Topic should be changed, "Area" => "Quadrilateral", then it would not be a duplicate since the others are for "polygon" (whatever point number is) and "rectangle". An optimized version for quadrilateral would be interresting and I couldn't find it here. My idea at the moment: it is inside if area of ABCD == area of ABG + area of  BCG + area of  CDG + area of DAG. Another solution It is inside if G is either in triangle ABC or in triangle ACD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific problem (quadrilateral - convex), you can do the following:
    1) calculate the equations for the 4 sides
    2) calculate the intersection of a vertical line which has G on it with each line
    3) if you find an even number of intersections, then it is outside
    4) if you find an odd number of intersections, then it is inside
    5) be careful at the endpoint intersections
    6) be careful if G is on one of the sides

Comment: Wait... in both cases it will be even, no? if inside the intersections will happen up and down, if outside up-up or down-down...

Comment: OK, your answer works if we add that the vertical line is not infinite on both sides, but only starts (and goes up or down), at G

Comment: I think you got it.  Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: one more case, we can still have Zero intersection, then it's outside...

Comment: I figured out my problem was not solved by solving this question, I just posted this in math, if you could have a look that would be nice :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554887/algorithm-to-discriminate-diagonals-in-a-set-of-6-segments-defined-by-4-points

Comment: Calculate the midpoint of each segment.  Then calculate if it is in the interior.  The midpoints of sides won't be in the interior.  They will be on the edge.

Comment: Zero intersections is even.